# Primefaces closedialog from back bean: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter key is null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I've a Primefaces (version 5) dialog binding with an attribute of my bean:

```
    <p:dialog 
    id="dialog"   
    widgetVar="myDialog" 
    modal="true" 
    resizable="false"
    appendTo="@(body)"
    binding="#{bean.dialog}"
>
...
<p:commandButton    
                id="cmdButton"
                action="#{bean.test()}" 
                value="Save"
                disabled="false" />
```

My back bean method is:

```
@ViewScoped
private Dialog dialog;
public Dialog getDialog() {
        return dialog;
}
public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
}

public void test( ) 
{
    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    rc.execute("PF('myDialog').hide();");
    rc.closeDialog(dialog);

}
```

When it runs, I get exception on closeDialog calling in back bean:

> Warning: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter key is null

Despite this, my dialog closing correctly.

Why this exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you annotate the field `private Dialog dialog;` with `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: To confirm, why are you closing the dialog from your backing bean?

Comment: For Tiny: @ViewScoped annotation is set on my bean

Comment: For WitYoBadSelf: my Dialog in xhtml page has a form to insert some informations with a button save. This button call a bean backing method that store data on database and at last must close Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces has two type of dialog implements:

1. p.dialog (as yours): dialog visibility is managed by using show() and hide() methods of the client side api.
2. Dialog Framework: dialog displayed in an external page which dynamically generated on runtime.

To answer your question:
1. Exception raised by "rc.closeDialog(dialog);" which should used in dialog framework. e.g.

```
public void selectResultFromDialog(Object result) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(result);
}
```

This will close the dialog and return the selected object to parent page.

2. Why my dialog closing correctly? 
   rc.execute("PF('myDialog').hide();") closed the dialog which actually hide it.

For your solution, I suggest you use the dialog framework.

Comment: I can't use Dialog Framework... is this only solution so?